# How to make an element stick only to it's container's top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

When the user is viewing my page on a mobile device I want my title to stick to the top of its container.
Each row has it's own title so as the user scrolls and the div is gone so should the title go and the new title should stick.

This is my HTML layout pretty much:

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content-one"></div>
        <div class="content-two"></div>
        <div class="content-three"></div>
        <div class="content-four"></div>
        <div class="content-five"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content-one"></div>
        <div class="content-two"></div>
        <div class="content-three"></div>
        <div class="content-four"></div>
        <div class="content-five"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content-one"></div>
        <div class="content-two"></div>
        <div class="content-three"></div>
        <div class="content-four"></div>
        <div class="content-five"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content-one"></div>
        <div class="content-two"></div>
        <div class="content-three"></div>
        <div class="content-four"></div>
        <div class="content-five"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="content-one"></div>
        <div class="content-two"></div>
        <div class="content-three"></div>
        <div class="content-four"></div>
        <div class="content-five"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a jquery solution please...

Comment: http://stickyjs.com/ try this plugin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on **Golwin**'s answer I added `position: relative;` to the **row** class,
and added `position: sticky; top: 0;` to the **title** class, and it worked.

```css
.page-container {
  border: 4px solid #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ;
}

.row {
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 4px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">title one</div>
    <div class="content one">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content two">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content three">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content four">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content five">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">title two</div>
    <div class="content one">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content two">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content three">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content four">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content five">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">title three</div>
    <div class="content one">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content two">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content three">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content four">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content five">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">title four</div>
    <div class="content one">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content two">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content three">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content four">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content five">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="title">title five</div>
    <div class="content one">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content two">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content three">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content four">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
    <div class="content five">Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet pig tri-tip meatloaf biltong, shoulder t-bone bresaola pastrami shank landjaeger short ribs. Pancetta porchetta t-bone tenderloin rump. Leberkas fatback pork belly filet mignon t-bone turkey tri-tip ham buffalo
      shoulder short loin. Tongue biltong tail leberkas. Doner pancetta turkey ribeye, swine strip steak pork loin venison beef ribs tenderloin shank turducken short ribs jerky meatball.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add `position relative` to **row** and `position absolute` and `top 0` to **title** class Then title will always stick at the top relative to row.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work.
I changed the title position to sticky and it worked.